# When I define a member in Obj-C with out @property, what's the action when deliver a value to the member?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, retain

```
@interface ClassA : UITableViewController {

    NSString *member;
}

@end
```

The member is declare like above.

if I use

```
NSString * astring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"???"];
member = astring;
```

Will the member retain the astring?

Comment: You should mention whether you're using ARC or not: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @CHrisH Got it, without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO it will not retain it. This is instance varaible (also called iVar). It does not release old object and does not retain the new object (as a typical declared property in setter).

//If property
`self.member = aString;` // call setter, equivalent to [self setMember:aString], the old value is released and a retain (or copy depending on property declaration) message is sent to aString.

If iVar
`member = aString` //No memory management.

Comment: o, I got it. One more question. If I use @property(nonatomic, copy), the member will copy the astring and when the astring is changed, the member won't be affected?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the compiler can make the final memory management of these two approaches fairly similar if you're using ARC (but your distinction between ivars and properties is well made)

Comment: Yes with ARC it is compiler responsible for memory management. Compiler to Dev "Don't worry let me insert retain/release code for you."

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is declared an instance variable (sometimes referred to as an "ivar") and pointed it to a string. Assigning the variable itself *will not retain the string* but in your example the string already has a retain count of 1 since you allocated it.

Depending on if you use ARC or not the string will be released at the end of the scope. If you are not using ARC you are responsible for releasing the string yourself. That being said, in your exact case `astring` is a string literal that will never be released so memory management is irrelevant in that case.

Comment: **Thank you**. I just don't understand the member without property how to act. I know I need to release the astring by myself.

Comment: Have a look at [the Memory Management Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) It explains retain/release in great detail